# Sumif row values from one column that are referenced from another

Tags: excel, sumifs

Looked a bit for this info but I'm stuck.

let's say I have two columns. I have to find top largest values from one column and sum the corresponding row values from the other column.

To find the values and average the result, I'm using the following formula (where c19 is the number of items to retrieve):

```
AVERAGE(LARGE('3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!B1:B1500;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C19))))
```

What I want now, is to retrieve and sum the matching row values from the second column. I can't seem to find a way to nest that formula.

Something like this?

Sumif
Range -

```
AVERAGE(LARGE('3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!B1:B1500;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C19))))
```

Criteria - ?????
Sum_range -

```
 '3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!C1:C1500;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C19)
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: You can use SUMIFS with `>=` than the result of LARGE as your criterion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still can't do it. Since I can't press enter here I'll edit my original post if you can then elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from BigBen's comment, something like this?

The formula in D4 is

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,">="&LARGE($B$2:$B$11,2),$A$2:$A$11)
```

and sums the values in A corresponding to the two largest values in B. From this you can easily average them.

[image]

It's also possible to use this with INDIRECT, viz
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, Not quite there though, I inserted the following formula, but got a #SPILL error: +SUMIF('3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!C1:C1500;">="&LARGE('3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!C1:C1500;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C19)));'3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!AI1:AI1500)

Comment: I think a spill error is caused when the results are spilling into a cell already occupied by something so try moving the output cells.

Comment: but if I replace the indirect with the number of rows to evaluate it works! thanks again

Comment: DEMO FILE: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ccba42b9116a9cbdcf8549e0d0c35bcd20201022102600/fa21d9

Comment: I just don't understand why does it spill with indirect! Shouldn't it just give 128 as the answer? And now I'm struggling with the same file, but now trying to get the SMALL formula if numbers are >0...

Comment: No because you are in effect treating it as an array and it shows all results. Look at my second pic above. The yellow 4 means you get 4 results, Large(x,1), Large(x,2) etc. If you just want one result just use c19.